# In using captureMessage in Sentry, how do I choose the type to be not classified as error?

Tags: python, sentry

In my Python app, I've got to intentionally log a variable coming through the function, to anticipate further error (somehow, intentionally the data got messed up). I use `sentry.captureMessage()` for this.

But turn out, it got classified as `error`, not what I have in mind as some sort of `message`, meaning we have false alarm because of this.

I have been going through the doc [here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/api/), but it seems like I can't make the message type to be of non error.

Anyway to make this captureMessage not causing error alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late but someone else might find his answer here. I just faced this issue and passing level='info' as keyword argument did the job (it seems it works the same way as in sentry breadcrumbs, which seem to be better solution for your situation btw).

```
sentry.captureMessage('My super important message.', level='info')
```